# How to invoke a method on textView when text is changed?

Tags: android, textview

I am developing an app for measuring heart rate. The idea is to display a customized message when heart rate is over 100. Is there a way I could check that condition on a textView on runtime.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Comment: check the answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use TextWatcher:

```
 EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_editext_id);
 edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  //display toast message
            }
        });
```

Comment: As I said I want to display a message when text is changed but I am not able to display toast here. Also I tried changing textview to edittext.
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
               newToast.show();
               
            }

Comment: It Still gives me an error. java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Toast.show()' on a null object reference

Comment: Method adterTextChanged works for me so thanks a lot for that. I am just not able to display a toast there, it gives me NullPointerException.

Comment: No need I was using it the wrong way! Got it right! Thanks a lot!